# Paypal IPN Listener Issue in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using subscribe now button of paypal and sandbox environment for testing and using ASP.net MVC3 as development environment.
After payment is done I checked in IPN history there response is showing as 200 and url is 
what i expected.

I created listener in Home controller  as follows.

```
[HttpPost] 
 public ActionResult paypalCallback()
    {

     //Doing some hardcoded DB insertions.
     DodbInsertion("Received");
     //Writing log file
     WriteLog("Ipn Log");
     Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     result.Add("Status", "Success");
     return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

}

In database nothing is writing and nothing happens in blog.
Then I make listener function a GET method and called from browser then log and DB insertion is happening .Ie db insertion and log function will work  correctly. But which was not working when it is called from Paypal IPN Listener.

Then I added   Response.StatusCode = 500; to listener function .Then in ipn history it is showing status as 500;
My application is published in godady. I don't know is there any relation with permission or something there.
Please help me Thanks in advance.
Syam.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel issue may be with your hosting environment Please check following 
http://helpnshareidea.blogspot.in/2013/11/mvc3-applications-in-windows-shared.html