# MVC3 Async function calling not working after hosting

Tags: c#

I am using MVC3 I have a function to send email I make that send email function to work asynchronously 
in local it works but when I am publishing in server it is not working.

I done as follows:
have a button click on clicking it will call An action names "CallSendEmail()" in controller Inside 
that function I am sync calling a private method for sending email.

Any body knows why it happens so?

Comment: What is not working? The e-mail is not being sent? What is the exact Exception, if any, being displayed?

Comment: Tony email is not send no exception is seen.Actually nothing happens.. Then a db insertion which was also not happening..What i feel when i call a function asyc it is not executing.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533042/paypal-ipn-listener-issue-in-c-sharp    This issue is also similar.. Because from paypal they are calling IPN listener async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following article..
http://helpnshareidea.blogspot.in/2013/11/mvc3-applications-in-windows-shared.html